# Clojure, Compojure-api: Access Request headers

Tags: clojure, ring, compojure-api

I am trying to implement request end point authentication. For that I want to access  accessToken value from request headers.

**My GET request end Point is**

**CURL Command**

```
curl -X GET \
  'http://localhost:3000/hello?id=10' \
  -H 'accesskey: 23423sfsdfsdfsfg' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'postman-token: f69b34e6-4888-ec31-5fbc-b734e176571b' \
  -d '{
    "artwork": {id" : 1}
}'
```

**HTTP Command**

```
GET /hello?id=10 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Content-Type: application/json
accessKey: 23423sfsdfsdfsfg
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: b974719d-5e1d-4d68-e910-e9ca50562b2f
```

**My Code for GET Method Implementation**

```
(defapi app
  (GET ["/hello/:id", :id #"[0-9]+" ] [id]
    (log/info "Function begins from here")
    (def artworkData (logic/artwork-id (->> id (re-find #"\d+") Long/parseLong)))
    (def data (if (not-empty artworkData)
               {:data artworkData :status 200}
               {:data [] :status 201}))
   (ok data)))
```

I want to fetch `accessKey: 23423sfsdfsdfsfg` from request header.

Is there any way to get the value and use in my GET Method?

I am using POSTMAN to test all API end points.

Answer (score 3):

Compojure has custom destructuring syntax (i.e., different from Clojure proper) for the parameters. You can [bind the whole *request map*](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/wiki/Destructuring-Syntax#request-binding) using keyword `:as`

```
(defapi app
  (GET ["/hello/:id", :id #"[0-9]+" ] [id :as request]
```

If you want only request headers, the following should work

```
(defapi app
  (GET ["/hello/:id", :id #"[0-9]+" ] [id :as {:headers headers}]
```

Note that this still allows you to bind path parameter `id`.

Comment: Thanks for quick Help.

Comment: I have posted answer to my question. Can you Please look into it?

Answer (score 1):

The Compojure Sweet API functions like `[compojure.api.sweet :refer [defroutes GET PUT context]]` let us bind the whole request or bind select headers.  In the snippet below `[:as request]` makes the whole request available to me.

```
  (GET
    "/download/:id"
    [:as request]
    :header-params [{x-http-request-id :- X-Http-Request-Id nil}]
    :path-params [id :- (describe String "The encoded id of the image")]
    :summary "Download the image bytes"
    :description "This endpoint responds 307 - Temporary Redirect to a cacheable presigned S3 URL for the actual bytes."
    (let [http-response (->> request
                             walk/keywordize-keys
                             util/extract-base-url
                             (transform/generate-resource-url (util/decode-key id))
                             status/temporary-redirect)
          expire-time (-> 3 hours from-now coerce/to-date ring-time/format-date)]
      (log/infof "x-http-request-id is %s" x-http-request-id)
      (response/header http-response "Expires" expire-time)))
```

1. The vector beginning `:header-params [{x-http-request-id :- X-Http-Request-Id nil}]` makes the value of the "X-HTTP-REQUEST-ID" header in the request available to my function directly as `x-http-request-id`.
2. The squiglies thing `{...}` makes the presence of x-http-request-id header optional in the request.
3. The `:- X-Http-Request-Id nil` stuff gives it a Schema which is defined somewhere else like `(s/defschema X-Http-Request-Id (rss/describe String "Request ID for tracing calls"))`.

Once you've got those kids bound to names you just work with the names.  The compojure folks don't do a great job at documenting everything you can do there.  Poke around their examples and you'll find stuff like this.

Answer (score -1):

I have figured out solution to the issue. Please check solution here.

```
(ns clojure-dauble-business-api.core
  (:require [compojure.api.sweet :refer :all]
            [ring.util.http-response :refer :all]
            [clojure-dauble-business-api.logic :as logic]
            [clojure.tools.logging :as log]
            [clojure-dauble-business-api.domain.artwork]
            [cheshire.core :as json])
  (:import [clojure_dauble_business_api.domain.artwork Artwork]))

(defapi app
  (GET ["/hello/:id", :id #"[0-9]+"] [id :as request]
    (log/info "Function begins from here" request)
    (def jsonString (json/generate-string (get-in request [:headers])))
    (log/info "Create - Access Key  is " (get-in (json/parse-string jsonString true) [:accesskey]))
    (def artworkData (logic/artwork-id (->> id (re-find #"\d+") Long/parseLong)))
    (def data (if (not-empty artworkData)
               {:data artworkData :status 200}
               {:data [] :status 201})))
```

I don't think it is smart way.

Can you anybody look into my solution and tell me Is there another way to get accesskey?

Comment: If you are building token/JWT/? authorization, maybe first look at ready-made authorization modules for Ring, like [buddy-auth](http://funcool.github.io/buddy-auth/latest/). I think you have an answer to  your original question of "accessing request headers". I would also appreciate, if you did not provide your own answer with essentially the same content as other (in this case, my) answers.

Comment: @Srini I wouldn't call it "not smart way", if it works its smart enough.  The shorter way to get at the header values, though, is through the ```:header-params``` mechanism.  Something like an access token is often done through middlewares in ring as you commonly need its logic across many routes.